# Which version gives a clear affordance on what happens when clicked?

Tags: copywriting, affordance, ux-writing

I'm designing a drill-down chart that allows users to analyze meter readings at various locations in a factory. They are able to isolate a single location and see trends of the readings over time. The screens below show hover and clicked states where users can focus on one location by clicking on it. the reset to default button below will reset both charts to their previous state, showing all the locations.

my question is what is the most appropriate word on the hover state? currently its **"click to view drill down"**, other options i'm considering are **"click to analyze"** or **"click to inspect"**

I believe based on that the reset below button would need to be aligned as well.

[image]

Comment: What is the wording the users use when doing this task? Do you have data for that?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Some of these are currently manual tasks, and things like weekly/daily trends are not calculated at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

The answer could be determined from talking to the users but also the purpose.

As per word definitions :

Inspect - To examine critically or carefully; especially, to search out problems or determine condition

Analyze - examine (something) methodically and in detail, typically in order to explain and interpret it

Drill-down - access successively deeper levels of a hierarchically organized database, set of files, etc.

So... it depends on what the reason is for users to access the further data.

Other than that you can use
Analyze instead of Click here to analyze
Inspect instead of Click here to inspect

Answer (score 1):

Drill down is a rather technical term, I doubt that it's intuitive enough to a layman.

I would remove the "click to", which goes without saying - just as on the button at the bottom you don't say "Click to reset to default" but just "Reset to default". I would just say "Inspect" or "Explore", which is my personal favorite.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, "click to inspect" makes the most sense to me as a user. Inspect is a word I'm familiar with (it's even in the right click menu for Google Chrome). Other options could be "expand" or "show more details".